# Quickfix won't parse :make output

Tags: quickfix, makeprg

My `makeprg` is set to:

```
cd build/ && cmake --build . --config Debug && ctest && gdb -q -ex run ./a
```

This allows me to build application, run tests and start debugging session sequentially in one command.

But I can't get gcc error report into quckfix:

```
...
make: *** [Makefile:115: all] Error 2

shell returned 2

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and then getting an error:

```
E40: Can't open errorfile /tmp/vkL411R/82
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How I would make quickfix working and being able to parse compiler output in this case?

Comment: I think `makeprg` is supposed to be  set to a single command which takes whatever parameters are supplied to `:make`. You might be able to get away with that by surrounding the whole thing with `{  .... ; }` (note spaces padding the brackets and the semicolon which must follow the end/last command). Better idea would be to put that all in an executable shell script and call that. Even then with your mix of cmake and gdb I don't know...there really should just be a cmake call in there, I would think. Only things that output the format vim expects to see.

Comment: If  you absolutely  had to have things other than cmake in there then you should send their output somewhere other than stdout....that's going to take some shell know-how. Really should move all that other stuff to separate step(s) (or part of the make target?).

Comment: @BLayer Yeah, surrounding with brackets works well in case if there compilation errors and execution chain breaks on `make` command. Thank you! But as side effect of that, `make` loses color highlighting for unknown reasons (while cmake itself not). As i know, Quickfix reads from stdout, and as I suppose vim shell output is stdout too. And if I'd redirect output somewhere else as you said, I think I wouldn't able to see it in vim shell or interact with it. Ok, I think the easiest way for now would be using `makeprg` that as it intended to used be - running make program only.

Comment: You can do some tricks with `sh -c`, and you *can* parse temporary files into the quickfix list (eg, the -q argument or one of the related functions). To actually solve your problem, though, we’ll need more information (and you may need to do some troubleshooting to see what’s going on)

Answer (score 1):

## Method #1

After some search I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102292/vim-make-to-compile-and-run-c-code-if-its-a-success) on SO.

According Mike's answer and other's notices in comments I modified that code slightly:

```
let &mp='cd build && cmake --build . --config Debug'

au QuickfixCmdPost make call TestAndRun()
function! TestAndRun()
  if len(filter(getqflist(), 'v:val.valid && v:val.type != "E"')) == 0
    !cd build/ && ctest && gdb -q -ex run ./a
  endif
endfunction
```

---

## Method #2

Before that I did some research on vim help and wrote this:

```
set makeef=/tmp/vim.err
set shellpipe=
let &mp='cd build && (make 2>&1\| tee ' . &makeef . ') && ctest && gdb -q -ex run ./a'
```

It works too, but very hacky.